# In NodeMCU, gpio.trig() not working as expected

Tags: gpio, nodemcu

In the [doc](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/gpio/), the syntax for gpio.trig is

```
gpio.trig(pin, [type [, callback_function]])
```

However, one of three cases yields an error:

```
gpio.mode( 8, gpio.INT )
gpio.trig( 8 )          -- this works
gpio.trig( 8, 'both' )  -- this bombs
-- ERROR: stdin:1: bad argument #3 to 'trig' (invalid callback type)s
```

Is there some nuance I'm missing here, or is there a bug in the doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feel free to verify and possibly report this on our GitHub issues list. I can't be sure but this may (but should not) happen if you already cleared the callback on a pin. The docs say

> Establish or clear a callback function to run on interrupt for a pin.

So, it may choke if you call `gpio.trig` multiple times on the same pin w/o a callback function.